# No FileSystem for scheme: cos

Tags: pyspark, data-science-experience, ibm-cloud-storage, stocator

I'm trying to connect to IBM Cloud Object Storage from IBM Data Science Experience:

```
access_key = 'XXX'
secret_key = 'XXX'
bucket = 'mybucket'
host = 'lon.ibmselect.objstor.com' 
service = 'mycos'

sqlCxt = SQLContext(sc)
hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hconf.set('fs.cos.myCos.access.key', access_key)
hconf.set('fs.cos.myCos.endpoint', 'http://' + host)
hconf.set('fs.cose.myCos.secret.key', secret_key)
hconf.set('fs.cos.service.v2.signer.type', 'false')

obj = 'mydata.tsv.gz'

rdd = sc.textFile('cos://{0}.{1}/{2}'.format(bucket, service, obj))
print(rdd.count())
```

This returns:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: cos
```

I'm guessing I need to use the 'cos' scheme based on the stocator [docs](https://github.com/SparkTC/stocator). However, the error suggests stocator isn't available or is an old version?

Any ideas?

---

**Update 1:**

I have also tried the following:

```
sqlCxt = SQLContext(sc)
hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hconf.set('fs.cos.impl', 'com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem')
hconf.set('fs.stocator.scheme.list', 'cos')
hconf.set('fs.stocator.cos.impl', 'com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient')
hconf.set('fs.stocator.cos.scheme', 'cos')
hconf.set('fs.cos.mycos.access.key', access_key)
hconf.set('fs.cos.mycos.endpoint', 'http://' + host)
hconf.set('fs.cos.mycos.secret.key', secret_key)
hconf.set('fs.cos.service.v2.signer.type', 'false')

service = 'mycos'
obj = 'mydata.tsv.gz'          
rdd = sc.textFile('cos://{0}.{1}/{2}'.format(bucket, service, obj))
print(rdd.count())
```

However, this time the response was:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.io.IOException: No object store for: cos
    at com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreVisitor.getStoreClient(ObjectStoreVisitor.java:121)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient
```

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Stocator (v1.0.9) that supports fs.cos scheme is not yet deployed on Spark aaService (It will be soon). Please use the stocator scheme "fs.s3d" to connect to your COS.

Example:

```
endpoint = 'endpointXXX' 
access_key = 'XXX'
secret_key = 'XXX'

prefix = "fs.s3d.service"
hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hconf.set(prefix + ".endpoint", endpoint)
hconf.set(prefix + ".access.key", access_key)
hconf.set(prefix + ".secret.key", secret_key)

bucket = 'mybucket'
obj = 'mydata.tsv.gz'

rdd = sc.textFile('s3d://{0}.service/{1}'.format(bucket, obj))
rdd.count()
```

Alternatively, you can use ibmos2spark. The lib is already installed on our service. Example:

```
import ibmos2spark

credentials = {
   'endpoint': 'endpointXXXX',
   'access_key': 'XXXX',
   'secret_key': 'XXXX'
}

configuration_name = 'os_configs' # any string you want
cos = ibmos2spark.CloudObjectStorage(sc, credentials, configuration_name)

bucket = 'mybucket'
obj = 'mydata.tsv.gz'
rdd = sc.textFile(cos.url(obj, bucket))
rdd.count()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like cos driver is not properly initialized. Try this configuration:

```
hconf.set('fs.cos.impl', 'com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem')

hconf.set('fs.stocator.scheme.list', 'cos')
hconf.set('fs.stocator.cos.impl', 'com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient')
hconf.set('fs.stocator.cos.scheme', 'cos')

hconf.set('fs.cos.mycos.access.key', access_key)
hconf.set('fs.cos.mycos.endpoint', 'http://' + host)
hconf.set('fs.cos.mycos.secret.key', secret_key)
hconf.set('fs.cos.service.v2.signer.type', 'false')
```

UPDATE 1:

You also need to ensure stocator classes are on the classpath. You can use packages system by exceuting pyspark in the following way:

```
./bin/pyspark --packages com.ibm.stocator:stocator:1.0.24
```

This works with `swift2d` and `cos` scheme.

UPDATE 2:

Just follow Stocator documentation (https://github.com/CODAIT/stocator). It contains all details how to install it, what branch to use, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @ChrisSnow Yes, but now it is not a configuration problem but library is missing. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stocator is on the classpath for Spark 2.0 and 2.1 kernels, but the `cos` scheme is not configured. You can access the config by executing the following in a Python notebook:

```
!cat $SPARK_CONF_DIR/core-site.xml
```

Look for the property `fs.stocator.scheme.list`. What I currently see is:

```
<property>
    <name>fs.stocator.scheme.list</name>
    <value>swift2d,swift,s3d</value>
</property>
```

I recommend that you raise a feature request against DSX to support the `cos` scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue, and to solve it I just changed environment:

Within IBM Watson Studio, if you start a a Jupyter notebook in an environment without a pre-configured spark cluster, than you get that error. Installing `PySpark` is not enough.

Instead, if you start a notebook with the Spark cluster available, you will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `.config("spark.hadoop.fs.stocator.scheme.list", "cos")` along with some others `fs.cos...` configurations.
Here's an end-to-end snippet code example that works (tested with `pyspark==2.3.2` and `Python 3.7.3`):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

stocator_jar = '/path/to/stocator-1.1.2-SNAPSHOT-IBM-SDK.jar'
cos_instance_name = '<myCosIntanceName>'
bucket_name = '<bucketName>'
s3_region = '<region>'
cos_iam_api_key = '*******'
iam_servicce_id = 'crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam-identity::<****************>'

spark_builder = (
    SparkSession
        .builder
        .appName('test_app'))

spark_builder.config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', stocator_jar)
spark_builder.config('spark.executor.extraClassPath', stocator_jar)
spark_builder.config(f"fs.cos.{cos_instance_name}.iam.api.key", cos_iam_api_key)
spark_builder.config(f"fs.cos.{cos_instance_name}.endpoint", f"s3.{s3_region}.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud")
spark_builder.config(f"fs.cos.{cos_instance_name}.iam.service.id", iam_servicce_id)
spark_builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.stocator.scheme.list", "cos")
spark_builder.config("spark.hadoop.fs.cos.impl", "com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem")
spark_builder.config("fs.stocator.cos.impl", "com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient")
spark_builder.config("fs.stocator.cos.scheme", "cos")

spark_sess = spark_builder.getOrCreate()

dataset = spark_sess.range(1, 10)
dataset = dataset.withColumnRenamed('id', 'user_idx')

dataset.repartition(1).write.csv(
    f'cos://{bucket_name}.{cos_instance_name}/test.csv',
    mode='overwrite',
    header=True)

spark_sess.stop()
print('done!')
```