# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com/ibm/stocator/fs/common/IStoreClient.setStocatorPath(Lcom/ibm/stocator/fs/common/StocatorPath;)V

Tags: pyspark, data-science-experience, ibm-cloud-storage, stocator

I'm trying to access data on IBM COS from Data Science Experience based on this [blog post](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/06/access-analyze-data-ibm-cross-region-cloud-object-storage/).

First, I select 1.0.8 version of stocator ...

```
!pip install --user --upgrade pixiedust
import pixiedust
pixiedust.installPackage("com.ibm.stocator:stocator:1.0.8")
```

Restarted kernel, then ...

```
access_key = 'xxxx'
secret_key = 'xxxx'
bucket = 'xxxx'
host = 'lon.ibmselect.objstor.com'

hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hconf.set("fs.s3d.service.endpoint", "http://" + host)
hconf.set("fs.s3d.service.access.key", access_key)
hconf.set("fs.s3d.service.secret.key", secret_key)

file = 'mydata_file.tsv.gz'

inputDataset = "s3d://{}.service/{}".format(bucket, file)

lines = sc.textFile(inputDataset, 1)
lines.count()
```

However, that results in the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com/ibm/stocator/fs/common/IStoreClient.setStocatorPath(Lcom/ibm/stocator/fs/common/StocatorPath;)V
    at com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem.initialize(ObjectStoreFileSystem.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:249)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:249)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:249)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:932)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:378)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:931)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

​**Note:** My first attempt at connecting to IBM COS resulted in a different error.  That attempt is captured here: [No FileSystem for scheme: cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011671/no-filesystem-for-scheme-cos)

Comment: Note: I first ran the script in the question without using pixiedust to install stocator.  There was an error, but unfortunately I didn't capture the error when running with the pre-installed stocator.  Iirc, the original error suggested stocator was not installed, which is why I then went on to use pixiedust to install stocator.

Comment: The problem was investigated.  The dedicated dsx environment in the UK that I was using does not have the correct version of stocator installed.  I will retry when the dependency has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't force-install a new Stocator unless you have a really good reason.

I highly recommend the Spark aaS documentation at:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/index-gentopic1.html#genTopProcId2

Please choose the correct COS endpoints from:

https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/endpoints

and PLEASE use the private endpoints if you're working from within the IBM Cloud.  It will be much faster and cheaper.

It's got examples of how to access COS data using all the nice helpers.  It'll boil down to

```
import ibmos2spark

credentials = {
  'endpoint': 's3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.service.networklayer.com',  #just an example. Your url might be different
  'access_key': 'my access key',
  'secret_key': 'my secret key'
}
bucket_name = 'my bucket name'
object_name = 'mydata_file.tsv.gz'

cos = ibmos2spark.CloudObjectStorage(sc, credentials)
lines = sc.textFile(cos.url(object_name, bucket_name),1)
lines.count()
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to install stocator it is already there. As Roland mentioned, new installation most likely would collide with the pre-installed one and cause conflicts.

Try ibmos2spark:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46035893/8558372

Let me know if you still facing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Chris, I usually don't use the  'http://' in the endpoint and that works for me. Not sure if that is the problem here.

Here is how I access the COS objects from DSX notebooks

```
endpoint = "s3-api.dal-us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net"

hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hconf.set("fs.s3d.service.endpoint",endpoint)
hconf.set("fs.s3d.service.access.key",Access_Key_ID)
hconf.set("fs.s3d.service.secret.key",Secret_Access_Key)

inputObject = "s3d://<bucket>.service/<file>"
myRDD = sc.textFile(inputObject,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

DSX has a version of stocator on the classpath for Spark 2.0 and Spark 2.1 kernels. The one you installed in your instance is likely to get into conflict with the pre-installed version.